# How to handle special characters in perl pie find replace

Tags: bash, perl

I have the following text in a file:

```
prompt **********************************************************************************
prompt **  Start
prompt **********************************************************************************
prompt **
prompt **  Calling:  FILE
prompt **
prompt **
@@FOLDER\FILE
prompt **
prompt **  commit
commit;
prompt **
prompt **
prompt **
prompt **********************************************************************************
prompt **  End
prompt **********************************************************************************
```

When I do

```
$ perl -pi -e "s/FILE/$file/g" ./tmp.sql;
```

It replaces all instances of the word FILE with whatever I have in $file, but when I call

```
$ perl -pi -e "s/FOLDER/$folder/g" ./tmp.sql;
```

Which just has the folder string, it coughs up, doesn't replace anything and the shell where I am calling it from spits out this stuff:

```
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
Unquoted string "g" may clash with future reserved word at -e line 1.
Unknown regexp modifier "/R" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/F" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/5" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/4" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/7" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/5" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/6" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/_" at -e line 1, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/2" at -e line 1, at end of line
```

Anyone know what gives?

Comment: What's in `$folder`? You aren't passing the value of `$folder` directly to Perl; you are dynamically building a Perl expression to be executed. If there is (as seems likely) a `/` in the value of `$folder`, that will terminate the `s//` expression, not be treated as part of the replacement text.

Comment: Yes it had a forward slash in it, I modified the value of the folder and that fixed it. Thank you

Comment: Changing the value of `folder` may not always be possible; see my answer for a change to the Perl code that is safe for *any* value of `folder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have `folder=/some/path`. Here is what your call to Perl looks like after the shell is done processing the line:

```
perl -pi -e "s/FOLDER//some/path/g" ./tmp.sql
```

The value of a shell variable is not passed into Perl; the shell performs simple text expansion on the string before Perl ever sees it.

If you were doing the replacement literally, you would realize you need to type something like

```
perl -pi -e "s/FOLDER/\/some\/path/g" ./tmp.sql
```

or

```
perl -pi -e "s|FOLDER|/some/path|g" ./tmp.sql
```

It is difficult either to properly escape the values in `$folder` or to "guess" a safe delimiter. The safest thing to do is to pass `$folder` as an extra argument.

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN {$replacement=shift}; s/FOLDER/$replacement/g' "$folder" ./tmp.sql
```

Comment: I know this is a different q but what if instead of tmp.sql I replaced "in-place" on a variable like: text=`cat ./tmp.sql` ... `perl -pi -e "s|FOLDER|$folder|g" $text`

Comment: You don't even need Perl for that: `text=${text//FOLDER/$folder}`.

Answer (score 3):

Slashes embedded in the `folder` variable are prematurely terminating the substitution

The easiest solution is to change the delimiters. Something like this should work

```
$ perl -pi -e "s{FOLDER}{$folder}g" tmp.sql
```

Comment: Probably, but not guaranteed, safe; `{` and `}` are both legal characters in a path name.

Answer (score 3):

Access the variable `$folder` from your shell environment as `$ENV{folder}` in Perl.

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/FOLDER/$ENV{folder}/g' ./tmp.sql
```

Note that this now uses 'single quotes' to delimit the code to execute.