# Not able to search and replace file using perl command in my shell script

Tags: shell

There is a group of file in different paths that i want to parse for a password pattern and change it with a new one.

For example i have a file `pass.lst` it contains password list

```
oldpassword1/newpassword1
oldpassword2/newpassword2
oldpassword2/newpassword2
```

I have one more file that contains file paths list
`path.lst`:

```
$Home/test.xml
$Home/demo.sh
etc....
```

Now i want to make main file that contains a script that reads input from both the file and does my work
Here is the script that i am using

```
  for i in `cat pass.lst`
     `do`
        for j in `cat path.lst`
          do
             perl -p -i -e 's/$i/g' $j
         done 
         done
```

But it's giving me this error.

```
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.
```

Any suggestions and help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to fix your script and fix formatting errors. Please check. Why do you use so many \`? Please paste your script on https://shellcheck.net and fix most common mistakes. The file does really contain the text `$Home` or does your folder with the files is named literally `$Home` or do you want somehow to expand `$Home` as a shell variable?

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: File contains $HOME as it refers to the home path, rest looks good! thanks for the editing that you did it seems ok now.

Comment: And something like `i="$i" perl -p -i -e 's/$ENV{i}/g' "$j"` will be closer to correct (someone who knows perl will be able to give you the actual syntax for looking up a string in the `ENV` hash).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy will try that

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38618279/14122 for an answer by someone who knows perl :)

Comment: ...the `i="$i"` part, btw, is what exports `i` from being a shell variable into an environment variable for the duration of the perl command.

Comment: BTW, what do you want to replace `$i` *with*? Right now, I see a *search* string in your code, but not any *replacement* string.

Comment: it would need to change to `'s/$ENV{i}/$ENV{replacement}/g'`, f/e, to replace instances of a `$i` with a `$replacement` (you'd need to export it the same way).

Comment: $i will read the text line by line from file pass.lst... what am i trying to do is to pass the perl command to all the files and do a global replace on the files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209543/discussion-between-mfjonez-and-charles-duffy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS=/ read -r orig replacement; do
  orig="$orig" replacement="$replacement" \
    xargs -d $'\n' \
    perl -p -i -e 's/$ENV{orig}/$ENV{replacement}/g' \
    <path.lst
done <pass.lst
```